# Why Are My Python Files Opening With VIDLE For Python?

Tags: python, ide, python-idle

For whatever reason my python files when I double click on them are opening VIDLE. Its super annoying because I have to right click and manually open it with the python terminal. Normally when you double click it opens with the python terminal. Yes I can do it manually but I have to use an IDE or manually run with the terminal. Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: The default program for `.py` files is set to VIDLE. Look up how to change the default program in you OS

Comment: that worked thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to work.

1. Find the file on your computer.
2. Right click and hover over open with and click choose another app.
3. Choose the app and at the bottom check always open with this app. Then click ok.